# How can I pour result db in array and send with json

Tags: php, json, ajax

How can I pour result db in array and send with json ?

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM myfeilds');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
```

Comment: you want to convert result  into json

Comment: yes i want send result and get js and print like this ::

Comment: $.each(orders, function(i, data) {
      $orders.append('<li>name: ' + data.name + 'family: ' + data.family + '</li>');

Comment: you can use `$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` than convert into json `$jsonResult = json_encode($results)` than echo or return it get in you JS  code

Comment: can u writ and sent to answer ?? please i am new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `json_encode` function to converting into json.

```
<?php 
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Contact', 'root', '');
$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM myfeilds');
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); /* it will give you array of result */

$jsonResult = json_encode($results) ; /* it will convert into json format */

echo $jsonResult ; /* this will show in  ajax success calling */ 
?>
```

for more `json_encode` you can read manual [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)